# How does this notation using theta mean a line or linear function?

Tags: notation, machine-learning

Question:

How does this notation using theta mean a line(ar function)?

Explanation:

I'm taking [Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course on Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/db3jS/model-representation). He often uses math notation without explaining it. He says...

> We're going to represent h as follows. And we will write this as
>   h (subscript theta) (x) equals theta (subscript one) plus theta (subscript one) of x. (see first green line of right of image below)

[image]

"h" above means hypothesis in machine learning but would commonly be called a function in math.

What I am really confused by and hoping for help understanding is ...

what does "theta (subscript one) plus theta (subscript one) of x" mean?

how does it represent a line or linear function?

I don't yet understand the correlation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more popular form of a straight line would be $$y=mx+c$$

Here $\theta_0$ corresponds to $c$ which is the intercept.

and $\theta_1$ corresponds to $m$ which is the gradient.

Comment: Wow! It took me a while to understand your answer but it's really elegant. Thank you. So c is the intercept because when x = 0, y = c. and m is the gradient because m determines the slope. Cool.

Comment: 2 more questions: 1. Is theta used here for a reason? Or is it a convention of some kind? 2. Is the use of Theta here a reference to the polar coordinate system or is it just coincidence?

Comment: it is just a symbol, it is not relevant to polar coordinate. another common notation is $\beta$ for this setting. They are parameters that we have to estimate in this setting.