# Why does Andrew Ng use the form h(x) = Theta subscript 0 + Theta subscript 1 x instead of the more common slope-intercept form?

Tags: notation, machine-learning

In this [course on machine Learning by Stanford](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/), Andrew Ng [describes a function for a line](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/lecture/rkTp3/cost-function) as h(x) = Theta subscript 0 + Theta subscript 1 x instead of the [more common slope-intercept form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope) y = mx + c.

Thanks to a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2901943/how-does-this-notation-using-theta-mean-a-line-or-linear-function), I now understand how both forms represent a line (via the y intercept and slope) but am unclear why Andrew Ng decided to use the Theta form of the equation rather than the more common slope-intercept form.

Can anyone help me understand this please?

Comment: $h(x)=\theta_0+\theta_1x$ **is** a common slope-intercept form. He just decided to **name** the parameters $c$ and $m$ differently.

Comment: I've never done Ng's ML course, but I'm guessing it is because that notation is commonly used in the context of gradient descent and cost functions.

Comment: notation like $\theta_0+\theta_1 x$ generalises much better than $c+mx$ to the situation where there are multiple variables, which is going to be of interest in ML.  But really it's a purely notational choice with no meaning.

Comment: Someone downvoted this question. Any ideas why? It was a lefitimate question and the answers have helped me enormously. So I am curious if I did something contrary to protocol here?